# How to use set methods to initialize instance variables via constructor in coffeescript

Tags: class, constructor, coffeescript, instance-variables, instance-methods

I have a "class" in coffee script whose instance variables I want to initialize with instance methods that return a value via a callback, but it doesn't work as I had hoped:

```
  EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter

  class MyClass extends EventEmitter
    constructor: ->
      @datamember: setDatamember()

    setDatamember: ->
      someFunction (response) ->
        @datamember = response
        @emit 'init'

    getDatamember: ->
      return @datamember

  ----

  myObj = new MyClass
  myObj.on 'init', ->
    console.log myObj.getDatamember
```

The result I get suggests that "this" in setDatamember is referring to something different from what "this" refers to in the object instance. If I explicitly call myObj.setDatamember, I get the expected result, but is there any way to call on a set method -- specifically one that sets the data member via a callback -- in the constructor? I've looked through the [docs](http://coffeescript.org/), as well as various other sources of coffeescript info (e.g. [this one](http://arcturo.github.io/library/coffeescript/03_classes.html)), and I haven't found anything that touches upon this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using a fat arrow for the anonymous function:

```
setDatamember: ->
  someFunction (response) =>
    @datamember = response
    @emit 'init'
```

Also, you'll need to call the correct function in the constructor:

```
constructor: ->
  @setDatamember()
```

In general, avoid fat arrows on methods - the way Coffee-Script implements this does some bad things to memory usage.  Also, it will rarely be necessary.

However, anonymous functions that refer to `this` will almost always need fat arrows.  `this` is not held in closure like normal variables, and will only be set by binding (`Function.prototype.bind`) or by calling it as an object method (`obj.myMethod()` will set `this` to `obj` in `myMethod`).

Answer (score 2):

Try using fat arrows on everything except the constructor:

```
 class MyClass
    constructor: ->
      @setDatamember()

    setDatamember: =>
      someFunction (response) =>
        @datamember = response

    getDatamember: =>
      return @datamember
```

However, you also look to have `someFunction` in there as an asynchronous function, so you'll never be able to just do

```
mc = new MyClass
console.log mc.datamember
```

Because that doesn't wait for `someFunction` to return before accessing `mc.datamember`.

Comment: Thanks -- I'll give this a try. I've also edited the example to correctly wait for the callback to return before accessing the data. Good catch.

Comment: I'm afraid it didn't work. Doing as you suggested with setDatamember (instead of @setDatamember) throws a Reference error: setDatamember not defined. If I use @setDatamember and use the fat arrow, I still have the problem where this doesn't refer to the object being constructed. =/

Comment: Sorry, answering quickly without testing. Try as above just invoking `          @setDatamember()` in the constructor

Comment: Be careful with fat arrows on class methods - they can cause memory issues at scale.  The only one that needs a fat arrow in this case is the callback to `someFunction`.

Comment: @AaronDufour, worked perfect. You might want to leave that as an answer, so I can mark it as such. Thanks.